# Need Monaco Editor For Custom Expression

Tags: monaco-editor

I am looking for a monaco editor language/configuration for something pretty custom.
I have been playing with the editor playground for custom languages: https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/playground.html#extending-language-services-custom-languages, but haven't quite gotten close to what I need.

I basically want a single-line expression editor where the user can enter items from a limited set of known functions and utilize a list of existing parameters and/or literals.

Almost something like the formula box in Excel, but with highlighting of known/unknown words, as general highlighting of invalid syntax.
Needs to allow nested evaluation

Examples:
This should be allowed:

```
ADD(1, AVG(1, 2, 4)-5*(STDDEV(@Param1, @Param2))
```

This should show as an error with "Foof" highlighted in red since it's not in the allowed list:

```
Foof(1, 2)
```

I am not too worried about type checking for now (adding string to bool to int), but bonus if that's incorporated.

ADD, AVG, STDDEV are all pulled from a known list. All other keywords (if we start with an existing language definition) need to be disallowed.

Don't want to support full C# style syntax. No code blocks {} allowed.
Array syntax [] can be allowed.

`Add(@SomeParamArray[5], @SomeParamArray[6])` should be allowed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a very broad question and as such not very useful for a Q&A site like Stackoverflow. Nonetheless let me give you a number of keypoints for the road laying ahead of you:

- Define your custom language with a Monarch syntax definintion, as a [language contribution](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/monarch.html). In the monaco-editor NPM package look in the monaco-editor/esm/vs/basic-languages/javascript folder for an example how the language contribution and definition files have to look like.
- Register both with Monaco:

```js
        languages.onLanguage(msg.id, () => {
            msg.loader().then((module: any) => {
                languages.setMonarchTokensProvider(msg.id, module.language);
                languages.setLanguageConfiguration(msg.id, module.languageConfiguration);
            });
        });
```

The value `msg` stands for a variable that defines your language extension point:

```js
export const msg: languages.ILanguageExtensionPoint & { [key: string]: any} = {
    id: "msg",
    extensions: [".msg"],
    aliases: ["MSG"],
    mimetypes: ["text/msg"],
    loader: (): any => import("./msg"),
};
```

- Create a parser which can be used to check the syntax of the input. Use that to add monaco-editor decorations to mark syntax errors.
- Optionally create code completion, hover and signature help providers to give the user support for writing input in your custom language.

Comment: Thanks @mike-lischke. I was/am close. I've actually made a copy of the CSHARP files and added my own entries to all the places in monaco where I see it referenced, but still have something off. All I've done, for now, is change the keywords to allow a very few. My highlighting theme does not seem to work. If I use my theme with the default CSHARP, it highlights, but as soon as I change the language to my own version, no highlighting, even with my only removing some keywords and basically using "csharp" as a starting point. Missing something simple, just not sure where.